# How to read secret using vaultsharp

Tags: c#, vault, vaultsharp

I have created a secret in the default `cubbyhole` secret engine named `secret1`.

Now I'd like to read this secret, which works fine from vault online CLI :

```
vault read cubbyhole/secret1
```

But with the following code :

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    ReadSecret().Wait();
}

public static async Task ReadSecret()
{
    IAuthMethodInfo authMethod = new TokenAuthMethodInfo("My Token");
    var vaultClientSettings = new VaultClientSettings("My Url", authMethod);
    IVaultClient vaultClient = new VaultClient(vaultClientSettings);
    Secret<SecretData> kv2Secret = await vaultClient.V1.Secrets.KeyValue.V2.ReadSecretAsync(path: "secret1");
    Console.WriteLine($"Secret data : {kv2Secret.Data}");
}
```

I get a *Permission Exception*.

I tried to change the code to :

```cs
Secret<SecretData> kv2Secret = await vaultClient.V1.Secrets.KeyValue.V2.ReadSecretAsync(path: "secret1", mountPoint: "cubbyhole");
```

And I get the error :
`System.AggregateException : 'One or more errors occurred. ({"errors":[]})'`

How can I read my secret ?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your issue. It is likely not the code but rather the token auth method failing (just a guess). `AggregateException` should contain inside of it two or more exceptions, what are the details of those? Can you provide the full PermisisonException error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KV2 != Cubbyhole

When struggling with the correct API path to use, remember that the vault binary has "-output-curl-string" which tells you the right way of asking for the path you're looking for.

```
# vault kv put cubbyhole/foo a=1
Success! Data written to: cubbyhole/foo

# vault kv get -output-curl-string cubbyhole/foo
curl -H "X-Vault-Token: $(vault print token)" -H "X-Vault-Request: true" http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/cubbyhole/foo
```

So the path you're looking for is not the KV nor KV2 path.